# Pull list of files ending in .csv.gz to download

Tags: linux

How can I go to a website (that requires a username and password) and pull the full website link of all files that end in .csv.gz into a .txt file (one line each). I don't want to pull data from sub folders.

For example I would want the following saves to my.txt

```
http://www.google.com/1.csv.gz
http://www.google.com/xyz.csv.gz
```

But it should not save

```
http://www.google.com/extra/abc.csv.gz
```

Answer (score 4):

With the HTTP protocol, unlike with FTP and some other protocols, there is no such thing as "pulling" a list of all files. If you want to fetch (`GET`) a file, you must know its URL.

Many web servers provide a convenience feature (often called autoindex) which, for a URL `http://site/directory/`, generates an HTML page containing a list of links to URLs of the form `http://site/directory/file` for each `file` that exists inside that directory on the server, hence providing a kind of pseudo file list which clients can discover. However, this feature is almost never used for the top level directory of a site (`http://site/`) because the site author will usually provide an explicit HTML page for top level URL of the site. Therefore, if `http://www.google.com/1.csv.gz` exists, you won't generally be able to find out about it unless you know ahead of time that it's there.

**If** you are dealing that a web server that is offering you an index of files, then you can quite easily munge that list from HTML into text with some text processing with `awk` or `sed` but it will depend on the exact format in which the particular web server is returning its HTML list...

```
curl http://site/ | sed -e [....]
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume all the files you want are listed in the index page of the web
site. If so you can use a text browser like **lynx** to dump the list of
urls found in that page, then with sed extract those you want. For example:

```
lynx -auth=ID:PASSWD -dump http://www.google.com |
sed '1,/^References/d
    \:www\.google\.com/[^/]*\.csv\.gz$:!d
    s/^ *[^ ]* //
' >my.txt
```

The sed deletes (d) all lines until the list of References (ie url links)
at the end. It then deletes lines not matching your pattern (`\:`
introduces a new pattern delimiter `:` instead of `/` so we can use / in the
pattern without esacping it). `[^/]*` matches any characters except `/`.
`$` is end of line. It then
removes the numbering lynx uses for the urls.